# Keeping track of downloaded torrent files

Tags: windows-7, utorrent, file-download, organizer-software

I have approximately 300-400 torrent files stored locally. Some of them I have used to download the related torrents, while others I have not. I need a way to keep track of which ones have been "used". It is tedious to manually write down which ones have been used in Notepad or Excel. Is there an easy software solution?

Comment: To answer this question, we need to know which [torrent software](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_von_BitTorrent-Clients) you are using (e.g. µTorrent).

Comment: yes  it is mu torrent but the links of torrents I have copy pasted from different sources and I have typed them in notepad and how did you type that word mu

Comment: Hold down ALT-key and type 0181 for a µ-char

Comment: ok and see if you can answer my original question

Comment: How about adding the torrent names to Excel? You could have 3 sheets - for to be downloaded, downloading and downloaded states.

Answer (score 2):

## µTorrent labels

(I assume you already have these little .torrent files of your 300-400 torrents? Not only blank URLs)

- Since you are already using µTorrent, you could use the [labels function](http://help.utorrent.com/customer/portal/articles/164816-what-are-labels-and-what-can-they-be-used-for-).
- With them you can create 2 separate lists named **not downloaded** and **already downloaded**
- you can assign labels [in bulk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtCGn.png)
- [start + stop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gv941.png) torrents in bulk from within the new list

  [image: µtorrent label list]

---

## Automatic labeling of new torrents

- the software [AutoLabeler](http://forum.utorrent.com/viewtopic.php?id=111432) labels all new torrents for you
- its written in AutoHotkey and has to run separately from µTorrent in the background
- configure it through the file `Labeler_Settings.ini` like this

  > [LABELS]
  > not downloaded =<kbd>.</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

I have a Python solution for finding files that you have not loaded into µTorrent. When you load a torrent file into µTorrent it will save a copy to `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\uTorrent`.

You can try comparing the contents of each folder but note that all torrents loaded into µTorrent will end up here even if they are not realized as completed downloads. So if you loaded the file and accidentally hit delete then this comparison would overlook those files.

In Python you could do something like the following:

```
import os
usedpath = '/users/username/appdata/roaming/utorrent'
folderpath = '/pathtoyourfolder' #python allows for /'s so you don't need c:\...\...\
for file in os.listdir(folderpath):
 if not file in os.listdir(usedpath):
  print(file, 'not used')
```

You could also save them to a file instead of displaying them to the screen. This works with Python 3.

To make sure the files in your AppData folder have actually been used is trickier to automate.